# How to show the most up-to-date satellite layer in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-earth

I am creating a simple embedded Google Maps viewer:

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 40.595139, lng: -3.983694 },
    zoom: 19,
    mapTypeId: "satellite",
  });
}
```

See the JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Peque/90yzhec1/

The code is resulting in this image being shown:

[image]

However, I know they have a more up-to-date image. I can see it in Google Earth and in Google Maps as well if I visit [the place at google.com](https://www.google.com/maps/place/40%C2%B035%2742.5%22N+3%C2%B059%2701.3%22W/@40.595139,-3.9842425,203m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d40.595139!4d-3.983694):

[image]

Funiest thing is, the same code shared above, when I click "Run" in JSFiddle (and if the browser window is not maximized nor in full screen), it briefly shows the more up-to-date picture first, only to cover it with the outdated version afterwards:

[image]

Is there any way to get the more up-to-date image shown instead? (or avoid the viewer to put the outdated version on top)

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @GülayKülekçi I wish! :-D